# How to integrate usrp n200 through redhawk 2.0.7?

Tags: usrp

I am trying to transmit a signal through usrp in redhawk 2.0.7.
For that I made a simple waveform and export it to target SDR in Redhawk explorer view. 
After that I have a made a node and include usrp uhd device in that node. I have exported this node project to target sdr. 
After that I have launched domain manager by right clicking on target sdr. By doing so, both GPP and usrp started in device manager. But when I launched waveform, it gives me error.

> Failed to create application. Failed to create usesdevice dependencies rh.USRP_UHD_1 for application. IDL:CF/ApplicationFactory/CreateApplication: 1.0

My question is how can I connect a component to a usrp device so that usrp can take input  from a component (e.g signal generator)to transmit signal over the air in transmission case, and  in receiving case, it can provide signal to component input port.

Answer (score 0):

Although your hardware has all the necessary components, RedHawk has not created the front-end interface to be able to transmit. The signal input ports are there on the USRP component (which is misleading), but they are basically just place-holders. You can receive signals through the RedHawk framework, but they have not yet released a version capable of transmitting (as of March 2018).